# How to split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters

Tags: java, string, whitespace, split

What regex pattern would need I to pass to  `java.lang.String.split()`  to split a String into an Array of substrings using all whitespace characters (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, etc.) as delimiters?

Answer (score 1004, accepted):

Something in the lines of

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```

This groups all white spaces as a delimiter.

So if I have the string:

```
"Hello[space character][tab character]World"
```

This should yield the strings `"Hello"` and `"World"` and omit the empty space between the `[space]` and the `[tab]`.

As VonC pointed out, the backslash should be escaped, because Java would first try to escape the string to a special character, and send *that* to be parsed. What you want, is the literal `"\s"`, which means, you need to pass `"\\s"`. It can get a bit confusing.

The `\\s` is equivalent to `[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]`.

Comment: Note that you need to `trim()` first: `trim().split("\\s++")` - otherwise, e.g. splitting `  a b c` will emit two empty strings first.

Comment: Why did you use four backslashes near the end of your answer? ie. `"\\\\s"`?

Comment: "".trim().split("\\s+")  - empty string split gives you a length of 1. 

"term".trim().split("\\s+")  - gives you also a length of 1.

Answer (score 91):

In most regex dialects there are a set of convenient character summaries you can use for this kind of thing - these are good ones to remember:

`\w` - Matches any word character.

`\W` - Matches any nonword character.

`\s` - Matches any white-space character.

`\S` - Matches anything but white-space characters.

`\d` - Matches any digit.

`\D` - Matches anything except digits.

A search for "Regex Cheatsheets" should reward you with a whole lot of useful summaries.

Comment: Useful link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Read Pattern class JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 69):

To get this working **in Javascript**, I had to do the following:

```
myString.split(/\s+/g)
```

Answer (score 37):

"\\s+" should do the trick

Comment: Why the + at the end?

Comment: @Anarelle it repeats the space character capture at least once, and as many time as possible: see [https://regex101.com/r/dT7wG9/1](https://regex101.com/r/dT7wG9/1) or [http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=\s%2B](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=\s%2B) or [http://regexper.com/#^s%2B](http://regexper.com/#^s%2B) or [http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=\s+&env=env_java](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=\s+&env=env_java)

Answer (score 13):

Also you may have a UniCode non-breaking space xA0...

```
String[] elements = s.split("[\\s\\xA0]+"); //include uniCode non-breaking
```

Comment: Indeed me too. I found this character at a response from ElasticSearch while I was trying to update the index aliases. The simple \\s+ did not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 10):

```
String string = "Ram is going to school";
String[] arrayOfString = string.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 9):

Apache Commons Lang has a method to split a string with whitespace characters as delimiters:

```
StringUtils.split("abc def")
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String)

This might be easier to use than a regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

To split a string with ***any Unicode whitespace***, you need to use

```
s.split("(?U)\\s+")
         ^^^^
```

The `(?U)` inline embedded flag option is the equivalent of [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) that enables `\s` shorthand character class to match any characters from the whitespace Unicode category.

If you want to split with whitespace and **keep the whitespaces in the resulting array**, use

```
s.split("(?U)(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2yoEt/2). See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/d2ZflI):

```
String s = "Hello\t World\u00A0»";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?U)\\s+"))); // => [Hello, World, »]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?U)(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)|(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)")));
// => [Hello,    , World,  , »]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a regular expression, and i'm assuming u would also not want non-alphanumeric chars like commas, dots, etc that could be surrounded by blanks (e.g. "one , two" should give [one][two]), it should be:

```
myString.split(/[\s\W]+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split a string by line break by using the following statement :

```
 String textStr[] = yourString.split("\\r?\\n");
```

you can split a string by Whitespace by using the following statement :

```
String textStr[] = yourString.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello   World";
String res[] = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

**All you need is** to split using the one of the special character of Java Ragex Engine,

and that is- **WhiteSpace Character**

- **\d**  Represents a digit: `[0-9]`
- **\D**  Represents a non-digit: `[^0-9]`
- **\s**  Represents a **whitespace character** including `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`
- **\S**  Represents a non-whitespace character as `[^\s]`
- **\v**  Represents a vertical whitespace character as `[\n\x0B\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029]`
- **\V**  Represents a non-vertical whitespace character as `[^\v]`
- **\w**  Represents a word character as `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
- **\W**  Represents a non-word character as `[^\w]`

**Here, the key point** to remember is that the small leter character `\s` represents all types of white spaces including a single space `[ ]` , tab characters `[        ]` or anything similar.

So, if you'll try will something like this-

```
String theString = "Java<a space><a tab>Programming"
String []allParts = theString.split("\\s+");
```

You will get the desired output.

---

**Some Very Useful Links:**

- [Split() method Best Examples](https://shubhamklogic.com/how-to-use-split-in-java-a-modern-guide/)
- [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)
- [split-Java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split)
- [RegularExpInfo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [PatternClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score -2):

Study this code.. good luck

```
    import java.util.*;
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input String : ");
        String s1 = input.nextLine();   
        String[] tokens = s1.split("[\\s\\xA0]+");      
        System.out.println(tokens.length);      
        for(String s : tokens){
            System.out.println(s);

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please detail your answer?