# How do I make Java ignore the number of spaces in a string when splitting?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Both of these Python lines gives me exactly the same list:

```
print("1 2 3".split())
print("1  2   3".split())
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
```

I was surprised when the Java 'equivalents' refused:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("1 2 3".split(" ")));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("1  2   3".split(" ")));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, , 2, , , 3]
```

How do I make Java ignore the number of spaces?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
"1  2  3".split(" +")

// original code, modified:
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("1 2 3".split(" +")));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList("1  2   3".split(" +")));
```

The argument passed to [`split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a Regex, so you can specify that you allow the separator to be one or more spaces.

I you also allow tabs and other white-space characters as separator, use "\s":

```
"1  2  3".split("\\s+")
```

And if you expect to have trailing or heading whitespaces like in `"  1 2   3   "`, use this:

```
 "  1 2   3   ".replaceAll("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "").split("\\s+")
```

Comment: Isn't the built-in `String.trim()` faster and a little more readable than `String.replaceAll("(^\\s+|\\s+$)", "")` or am I missing something ?

Comment: ^^ True, but then he wouldn't have the opportunity to show off his 1337 REGEX SKLZ. ;-)

Comment: haha :-) I was thinking that trim was only triming the space character

Comment: Worked flawlessly. I didn't realize that split() didn't consider &*#&ing leading whitespace so thanks for mentioning that issue in particular.

Comment: @arnaud576875 Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

How about using a neat [regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)? Note that according to Java API documentation, [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) will take a regular expression string parameter.

```
"1 2   3".split("\\s+")
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do:

```
yourString.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `"1  2  3".split("\s+")` than `"1  2  3".split(" +")`.
When you use `\s` instead of " " it is more readable and safer.