# Processing a user's input?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am getting user input on the column, row number and data they want to put in that place. How would I go about breaking the user input into pieces ? The user input will always be in the COLUMN ROW DATA format so is there any delimiter statement that I can use ?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far, a sample of the input, and describe specifically what is not working as you want it.

Comment: please elebrate your question very clearly

Comment: @Ashley Your question is a bit vague. Could you edit it for clarity? Pretend you've never seen your application before, or know anything about the problem at hand. Your question needs to explain both things.

Comment: okay so like I take in user inputs from the user and sometimes things are optional. Like A user can input `find column# hello` so it would go find in the column# the user gave the word hello. but a user can say `find hello`. so I have to process user input according to what the user gave me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user input is a string in the format:

```
<col> <row> <data>
```

You can use the split() method on the space (" ") to get an array of strings.

For example

```
input = "3 2 100";
inputs = input.split(" ");
column = inputs[0];           // "3"
row = inputs[1];              // "2"
data = inputs[2];             // "100"
```

If this isn't what you're looking for then please elaborate your question.

Comment: if it there is a lot of spaces between them like 3      2      100 it wouldn't matter ?

Comment: @Ashley Check this question for splitting on any whitespace: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)