# Difference between splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens and split

Tags: java, apache-commons

What is the difference between `StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens()` and `String.split()`?

With `splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens`, we could limit the number of parameters that are returned in an array. Is this the only difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**java.lang.String.split();**
*Usage:*
The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.  The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string.  If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

**org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens();**
*Usage:*
Splits the provided text into an array, separator specified, preserving all tokens, **including empty tokens** created by adjacent separators. This is an alternative to using StringTokenizer.

Read more: [kickjava_src_apache_StringUtils](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.htm#ixzz1hpBSk4ld)

and `String.split()` uses the final class `Pattern` to split.

```
Pattern.compile(regex).split(this , limit);
```

in StringUtils uses `splitWorker(String str, char separatorChar, boolean preserveAllTokens)` , it's own method, which is a Performance tune for 2.0 (JDK1.4).

Comment: Doesn't split include empty tokens?

Comment: you can find out exact answer from this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Comment: Thanks Azad. I am using comma as separator , so I guess here shouldn't be any issues with String.split(). But I would be losing the performance improvement provided by StringUtils splitworker and I would have to handle null by myself.

Comment: Yes @user1042646 you need to handle null while using String.split. all the best :)

Answer (score 2):

```
I found folowing difference between String.split and splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens
```

- splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens handles Null values where
  String.split() doesn't
- In splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokensAdjacent separators are
  treated as separators for empty tokens.