# How to split the following string in java?

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to split the following string primarily based on whitespace. Please refer to the following example

```
Name:"John Adam"  languge:"english"  Date:" August 2011"
```

I need to split the text based on each parameter. For e.g.

```
Name:"John Adam"

languge:"english"

Date:" August 2011"
```

I'm not able to construct the right regex for this scenario.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: Is the `languge"english"` a mistake or thats how it is?

Comment: there's no `:` between languge and "english" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate/might be helpful to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. I've fixed it now. @Aurora .. The reference you've given splits  based on whitespace. In my case, it won't work since it'll split "John" and "Adam" as well.

Comment: [Java Regex Test Applet](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html) is a good tool for such stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String input = "Name:\"John Adam\"  languge:\"english\"  Date:\" August 2011\"";
    // You can define this pattern statically.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\:\\\".*?\\\")\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    List<String> keyValues = new LinkedList<String>();
    while(matcher.find()){
        keyValues.add(matcher.group());
    }

    //keyValues == [Name:"John Adam"  , languge:"english"  , Date:" August 2011"]
```

Comment: Excellent stuff, this is the regex I was looking for, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the class [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).. so to split something with whitespaces you could do something like:

```
String name=" Hello world 2011";
    StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(name);
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
        }
```

and that should split it to:

> Hello
>   world
>   2011

this little tutorial could help you:
http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/java/java5.php

Comment: Argh, you beat me by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look first at using String.split() in two passes: the first splitting on a space character, the second on double-quotes.

Comment: This won't work. I think you mean the other way around? Clearly splitting on spaces first will give you the token `Name:"John`, which is not intentional.

Comment: @stefan ... you are right, the whitespace splitting won't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler not to use a regular expression.  Just have a loop that looks for a colon, then for a double-quote, then another double-quote, then for whitespace.  (OK, use a regular expression for the whitespace bit).  As the loop proceeds, you'll get a String for the key, and a String for the value.  You'd break the loop as soon as you fail to find the character that you're looking for.

Comment on this answer if it's not clear how to do this, and I'll post some code.  But I think I've given you enough to get started.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ourStr = "Name:\"John Adam\"  languge:\"english\"  Date:\" August 2011\"";

String[] newStr = ourStr.split(" ");

for(int i=0;i<newStr.length;i++) {
   System.out.println(newStr[i] + "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Name:"John Adam"

languge:"english"

Date:" August 2011"
```