# How to remove part of the string in java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

I want to break up a string in java. I have a string "message.txt.cpabe".I want to remove the last portion and only want "message.txt". How do I do it?

Comment: try doing some googling and trying please

Comment: Please ask some quality question. You can easily get answer from any search engine.

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = "message.txt.cpabe";
int indexOfLast = s.lastIndexOf(".");
String newString = s;
if(indexOfLast >= 0) newString = s.substring(0, indexOfLast);
System.out.println(newString); // prints "message.txt"
```

Comment: I would guard against lastIndexOf returning -1, which in turn will cause substring to throw an exception.

Comment: ah, spoon feeding is not a great idea. (:

Answer (score 2):

I would use [LastIndexOf(".")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) to get the index of that last '.', and then use [substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to cut out the part that you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="message.txt.cpabe";
str=str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Try this.

Answer (score -2):

Probably not what you wanted but certainly what you asked for.. :-)

```
String original = "message.txt.cpabe";
original = "message.txt";
```