# How to extract strings

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming. I want to write simple Java network protocol.
I want to send this string to remote Java host, for example:

```
230 computer delete reboot exit
```

The problem that I cannot resolve is how I can extract the strings one by one and put it into array? And the biggest mystery to me is how I do this if I have strings with different length?
Thank you for your help!

PS: Can I send directly entire array not just simple strings?

PS 2: What if I have Java server and C client? As far as know only strings can be used to exchange data between both sides?

Comment: I can't speak about sending to a remote Java host, but one can convert a string to an array with the `.split()` function. `"230 computer delete reboot exit".split("\\s+")` will split your string by whitespace into an array of 5 elements.

Comment: you don't know it yet, but this isn't your *biggest* problem ...

Comment: Would you please share your experience?

Comment: You have to decide how you want to serialize your data, if you want to send something more complicated like arrays. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats for some alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. Split the strings using `String.split` method

   ```
   String text = "230 computer delete reboot exit";
   String[] split = text.split("\\s");
   ```
2. Using a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`

   ```
   String text = "230 computer delete reboot exit";
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\s+(.*)\\s+(.*)\\s+(.*)\\s+(.*)");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
   if (m.matches()) {
       String first = m.group(1);
       String second = m.group(2);
       ....
   ```
3. Using a `Scanner` class

   ```
   Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
   int firstNumber = s.nextInt(); // 230
   String secondText = s.next(); // computer
   ....
   ```

The second and the third choice could be superior if read stuff from a stream.

Or some other method... :)

Comment: One more question: If I want to connect Java server and C client what is the most elective way to exchange data? Strings?

Comment: Define a binary or textual protocol. In your case you can start with strings just like you defined in your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
String input = "230 computer delete reboot exit";
String s[] = input.split("\\s+");

// now s[0] = 230 s[1] = computer
```

Read more on [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

And the regex used here `\\s+` is equal to any whitespace. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

You can send directly an array by using serialization through [`ObectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).

But I suggest you to use your own classes to encapsulate messages. Eg

```
class NetworkMessage {
  int code;
  String param1;
  String param2;
  ..
}
```

So that it's more object oriented and structured. Sending just strings is not a good design, especially if the protocol grows in complexity.

Regarding splitting the string just use `String.split(String regex)` method but it's not a good solution.