# how can i split this string which is get from a html document with using jsoup at java?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

```
<div class="listPrice" style="font-size: 12px; padding: 10px 0 0 0;"> HSN Price:&nbsp;$9.95 </div>
```

Hi i am trying to split this with its' spaces but " " is making some problem for me. I am writing code at java with using jsoup. I send `element.text().split(" ");` but this or `element.text().split("&nbsp;");` cant execute at " " 
Cn you help me about this situation?

Comment: was good solution for whitespaces but i need execute this for a html element.

Comment: What info are you trying to extract?

Comment: Could you tell us more why split(" ") is bad for you because `" " is making some problem for me` is kind of vague

Comment: i need to extract price value only and just trying to split that text but it comes with "&nbsp;" so i am asking this value have a special char name or something for split ? so i only need $9.95

Comment: @Pshemo i just encounter with this problem my element.text() value is "HSN Price: $199.00" for this but i cant split this with using str.split(" ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the price is what you are after you could try with something like

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\$.*)\\s*</div>").matcher(element.text());
String price = null;
if (matcher.find()) {
  price = matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to escape the $. Now it works.