# Split String FullName

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

I need to split full name so I return just the surname.

For example F. J. Hill (we assume that last name is always after first name or after initials)

so this is what i got so far

```
public String getLastName(){
    String surname;
    surname = FullName.split;
}
```

but this doesn't work. Can i get some help please ? Dont really understand how split string works

Comment: Please go through the documentation of `String#split` method. It just requires a google search.

Comment: Firstly, in Java you have to put parentheses (`()`) after a method name to call it. The last line of your method should be `surname = FullName.split([parameters]);`. And don't forget to return a value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you see if this solves your answer?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "F. J. Hill";
        String[] split = name.split(" ");
        int size = split.length - 1;
        System.out.println(split[size]);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you look at the full name from the back ?