# How to split string in Java on whitespace?

Tags: java, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Yes, I tried to search it on google and stackoverflow, but no good results. I have a string, lets say: "Lets do some coding in Java" and I would like to got strings (split it on whitespaces):

Lets, do, some, coding, in, Java

I used `string.split("\\s")` for this, but know I need to use regex instead. Any ideas?

Comment: `"\\s"` is a Regex for a single whitespace character, see the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Using google with "java regex split" gives you all the information you need..,

Comment: If you see the documentation of `String.split()`, it takes Regex as parameter only to split.

Comment: `String.split()` takes a regexp as parameter so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you even look at the JavaDocs for split http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String). It cleary says that it takes a regex.

Comment: I agree with @CraigSuchanec. Split takes a regex

Answer (score 12):

```
String str = "Hello How are you";
String arrayString[] = str.split("\\s+")
```

Please use this

Comment: is this ok, he mentioned that as String that's why I followed.Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

to specify space as splitting char, you can pass `" "` as parameter to `String#split`.
Example:

```
String test="Lets do some coding in Java";
    for(String token : test.split(" "))
        System.out.println(token);
```

Comment: Better to use `\\s+` for splitting on any number of spaces.

Comment: it won't work it has multiple space.String s ="hello    sorry".

Comment: It has one space, my code would split "hello sorry" in "hello" and "sorry" (try).  It won't handle the case in which the test phrase has multiple spaces, as @RohitJain pointed out. Your solution is better than mine because is more general.