# Android split tag

Tags: android, regex, jsoup

In my jsoup class, i retrive the text of each tag as follows

```
  doc = Jsoup.parse(getxml,"", Parser.xmlParser());
    libelle = doc.select("belle");
```

resulting in pin pin pin apple apple apple 34233 4433 314434

then i split it as

```
  libel = libelleCompte.text().toString().split(" ");
```

the original tag is as follows

```
<pretty>
<belle> pin pin pin</belle>
<belle>apple apple apple</belle>
<belle>34233</belle>
<belle>4433</belle>
<belle>314434</belle>
</pretty>
```

the result should be

pin pin pin
apple apple apple
34233
4433
314434

any idea of how to split it after each tag  ?

Comment: What is the current outcome with you're current code?

Comment: Your "resuling in" and "the result should be" strings are the same in your question. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @yakusha Does the following answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited:***

You can't do it with simple regex, although the following code can help you:

```
    String testStr = "pin pin pin apple apple apple 34233 4433 314434";
    String[] splitedText = testStr.split("\\s+");
    ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int strCounter = 2;
    String tmpStr = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < splitedText.length; i++)
    {
        tmpStr += splitedText[i] + " ";
        if (strCounter == i)
        {
            tmpArray.add(tmpStr);
            tmpStr = "";
            strCounter += 3;
        }
    }

    // Test for result
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpArray.size(); i++)
        Log.w("Counter", i + " => " + tmpArray.get(i));
```

**Result:**

> 0 => pin  pin  pin
>
> 1 => apple  apple  apple
>
> 2 => 34233  4433  314434

**Note:** The `\\s` is equivalent to `[\\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]`.

Comment: nope i want index 0 1 2 to be on the same line index 3 4 5 on second line and the remaining on a respective index that is each <belle> tag should have a unique index

Comment: ok but the content is dynamic, there can be 3 or more words in a sentence. so . dont worry thanks i'll mark you as the right answer though my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello How are you";
String arrayString[] = str.split("\\s+")
```

See below link:-

[How to split string in Java on whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496437/how-to-split-string-in-java-on-whitespace)