# How to split sentence into words separated by multiple spaces?

Tags: scala

The following code:

```
val sentence = "1 2  3   4".split(" ")
```

gives me:

```
Array(1, 2, "", 3, "", "", 4)
```

but I'd rather want to have only the words:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

How can I split the sentence when the words are separated by multiple spaces?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters 

this worked.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
scala> "1   2 3".split(" +")
res1: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

The "+" means "one or more of the previous" (previous being a space).

Better yet, if you want to split on all whitespace:

```
scala> "1   2 3".split("\\s+")
res2: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

(Where `"\\s"` is a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) which matches any whitespace.  Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more examples.)

Comment: cf. "1   2 3".split("""\s+""") is the same as "1   2 3".split("\\s+") in Scala. Raw string (string wrapped in """) is useful in complex pattern.

Comment: NB. For strings starting with whitespace: " 1   2 3".split("\\s+"), this gives a result with who's first element is an empty string. Is there a regex that will avoid this?

Comment: @user48956 " 1 2 3".trim.split("\\s+")

Comment: In a file text "\n\n".trim.split(" +") gives Array[String] = Array("") .. an empty string.. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 5):

You can filter out the `""` from the split `Array`.

```
scala> val sentence = "1 2  3   4".split(" ").filterNot(_ == "")
sentence: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: This one works too but I found another trivial answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression `\\W+` delivers (alphaunmerical) words, thus

```
val sentence = "1 2  3   4".split("\\W+")
sentence: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

For ease of use, in Scala 2.10.* and 2.11.* consider

```
implicit class RichString(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def words = s.split("\\W+")
}
```

Thus,

```
sentence.words
res: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```