# Make an email list, by entering only recipient names

Tags: java, email, names

I want to make a simple code, that prompts you to enter names, separated by comma or just a space, and when you click enter, to take every one word you entered, and put a @gmail.com at the end of it, how can I do it?
That's what I have for now

```java
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mail = "@gmail.com";
    String names;
    System.out.println("Enter names: ");
    names = input.next();
    System.out.println(names + mail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be everything you asked for, if you put a list of names separated by commas it will loop through them, otherwise it will just print a single name.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String mail = "@gmail.com";
    System.out.println("Enter names: ");
    String names = input.next();
    if(names.contains(",")) {
            for(String name : names.split(",")) {
                    System.out.println(name + mail);
            }
    } else {
            System.out.println(names + mail);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks!
But why it doesn't work with a space?

Comment: You'll need to add a solution from this list as spaces don't work: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what language this is, here's the pseudo-code:

```
names = input.next();
namesArray = names.split(" ") -- replace with your preferred delimiter
foreach name in namesArray
  print name + mail
```

Comment: what about the foreach part and the print one? please explain

Comment: RTFM: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html
For print, you can use your System.out.println(names + mail);

Comment: sorry if I will sound rude, I don't know if you understand from the noob question, but I am a beginner. So could you PLEASE write the whole code with the "for" part?

Comment: well, nothing, I don't know how I can use a separator such as space, to have it do what I want...
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String mail = "@gmail.com";
  String names;
  System.out.println("Enter names: ");
  names = input.next();
  String[] namesArray = names.split(" "); 
  for (names : namesArray) {
   System.out.println(names + mail);
  }