# how do I use .split on formatted text

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, split

**My users copy data from another website that looks like this:**

[image: flight-tickets]

**Which looks like this when pasted:**

> Houston (IAH) to Cancun (CUN) - Fri, Jul 12
>   United United 1084 Dep: 6:58PM Arr: 9:15PM 2h 17m  Boeing 737   Economy (E)
>
> Cancun (CUN) to Houston (IAH) - Sun, Jul 14
>   United United 1017 Dep: 2:00PM Arr: 4:23PM 2h 23m  Boeing 737   Economy (E)

**I am parsing the text that is copied with the below.**

```
var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById("fltInput").value.split('\n');
var arrayOfWords = arrayOfLines[1].split(" ");
```

I would expect `arrayOfWords[1]` to be `United` and `arrayOfWords[2]` to be `1084`, but instead I get `1084 Dep:` and `6:58PM   Arr::`

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/zT38R/5/). (Slide the slider on the page to see what I mean.)

Clearly the problem is with `.split(" ")` not seeing the different cells in the copied table as spaces and therefore not splitting the text where I expect.

**How can I get around this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below regex to split on any whitespace solved this for me thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9525071/1376624)

```
var arrayOfWords = arrayOfLines[1].split(/\s+/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because your strings are not seperated uniformly with single spaces. They may have double or triple spaces in between.

A modified version splitting on 3 spaces:

http://jsfiddle.net/zT38R/6/

```
var arrayOfLines = document.getElementById("fltInput").value.split('\n');
 console.log(arrayOfLines);
var arrayOfWords = arrayOfLines[1].split("  ");// changed here
```

Either format your input correctly.
Or better use regex based parsing of data.

Comment: Yeah, found a fix using regex, Thank you!