# How to divide a line in excel and store in array when they have different spaces between them

Tags: java

Hi,

I'm trying to retreive the data from excel sheet using java.
Please tell me how can I divide following lines into array like
0th element is 0171185 
1st element is 11200113
2nd element is 404630G 40X46 1.2-MIL GRAY

One of the line is

0171185(MORE THAN A TAB SPACE)11200113 (MORE THAN A TAB SPACE)404630G 40X46 1.2-MIL GRAY

Comment: Have you tries anything, if yes please provide the code.

Comment: What have you tried? You can try String split http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Yes I have used           ItemDescdup=fouritems.get(id).split("\\s+"); 
 but it is dividing irrespective of spaces , like when it finds a space it divides and stores with an index.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your line is stored in a `String` called `myString`:

```
myString.split("[\\W]{2,}"))
```

will use "more than one space or tabulator" as your delimitor. So single spaces and/or tabulators will not split your tokens.

**Edit:** as noted by Litari, `\\s` is also possible instead of `\\W` depending on which characters you want to split exactly.

Comment: Hiiiiiiii, thank you sooo much i got it :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If your problem is solved now, please accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here previously: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

The short answer is, use `\\s` as delimiter since it's equivalent to `[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response ........ But am not getting any items in array