# How do I set the contents of a JTextPane or JTextArea to a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane

How do I set the contents of a `JTextPane` to a `String array`? I'm making a memorization application that removes random words that a user enters in a `JTextPane` and replaces it with underscores. I want to convert what the user enters to a `string array` with each index being a separate word.

Does anybody have any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure where to start. I have created the frame and blank classes. I was thinking that there may be a way to determine separate words because of spaces.

Comment: Yes certainly there is a way to do that. Take a look to this question: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Answer (score 4):

Some tips:

- Get the text from `JTextArea` or `JTextPane` through `getText()` method. It will return a `String`
- Split the `String` by white spaces. Take a look to this answer: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters/225360#225360). You'll have a `String[]` as desired.
- Do your random replacements.
- Set text back to the `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javax.swing.text.Utilities`. It has 2 methods

```
public static final int getWordStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getWordEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

You can start from 0 offset and search for the next word end. Then start search next word start after the end of the first word etc.

The methods use locale dependent word break iterator.

```
BreakIterator.getWordInstance(c.getLocale())
```