# Iterating through a hashset and printing the result

Tags: java, printing, hashset

I am trying to use the getWordSet() method from my WordGroup class on the 2 wordgroups in my Main class and loop over the hashset returned and print out the result but it isn't even compiling. My attempt at the code which I hoped would do it is in the bottom of my main class between the asterisks. Can somebody help me please? EDIT: I have implemented teh changes suggested as shown in my code below and this has lead to a new problem- I want both wordgroups to go into the same set but when I tried changing hashSTwo to hashSOne in an attempt to get all teh words into hashSOne it wouldn't compile.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        WordGroup wordgroupOne= new WordGroup ("You can discover more about a person in an hour of play than in a year of conversation");
        WordGroup wordgroupTwo= new WordGroup ( "When you play play hard when you work dont play at all");

        String[] quoteOne = wordgroupOne.getWordArray();   
        String[] quoteTwo = wordgroupTwo.getWordArray();

        for (String words : quoteOne){
            System.out.println(words);
        }

        for (String words : quoteTwo){                       
            System.out.println(words);
        }

        **HashSet<String> hashSOne = wordgroupOne.getWordSet();
        HashSet<String> hashSTwo = wordgroupTwo.getWordSet();

        for (String set : hashSOne){
            System.out.println(set);
        }

        for (String set : hashSTwo){
            System.out.println(set);
        }**
    }
}
```

WordGroup set:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordGroup {  
    public String words;

    public WordGroup (String getWords){
        words = getWords.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String[] getWordArray(){
        return words.split(" ");   
    }

    public HashSet<String> getWordSet(){
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        String[] p = getWordArray();
        for (String items : p){
            set.add(items);
        }
        System.out.println(set);
        return set;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getWordCounts() {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] q = getWordArray();
        for (String stuff : q) {
            Integer oldVal = map.get(stuff);
            if (oldVal == null){
                oldVal = 0;
            }
            map.put(stuff, oldVal+1);
        }
        System.out.println(map);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: `but it isn't working` is not best way to explain problem. Maybe add more details about how should it work and how it behaves now.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: What's not working exactly ?

Comment: It isn't working doesn't help. What happens **precisely**? Any error message? If so, paste it in your question. Tell us what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `getWordSet()` on `quoteOne` since it is `String[]` and it doesn't have such method. You probably want to use it on `wordgroupOne` which is `WordGroup` type. Same goes for `quoteTwo`.

Also you should prefer [programming on interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1393766) rather than actual classes if possible so maybe change your method to return `Set` rather than `HashSet`.

---

> How would I go about putting both results in the same hashset? I tried changing them to both hashSOne and it just wrote over my first hashset with the second

You probably did

```
hashSOne = hashSTwo;
```

which just makes `hashSOne` reference use set from `hashSTwo` reference.

If you want to create new set that will contain all items from both sets you can do it this way

```
//lets create Set with elements from first set
Set<String> allElements = new HashSet<>(hashSOne);

//now lets add all elements from second set 
allElements.addAll(hashSTwo);//this will not add duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start by looking at that getWordArray() method. I suspect your regex there is a bit dodge.
See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters) link for a whitespace split regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be more specific in what the error is for future posts. It can be very difficult to find what the error is without the compilers help.

```
HashSet<String> hashSOne = quoteOne.getWordSet();
HashSet<String> hashSTwo = quoteTwo.getWordSet();
```

should be

```
HashSet<String> hashSOne = wordgroupOne.getWordSet();
HashSet<String> hashSTwo = wordgroupTwo.getWordSet();
```

Comment: Thanks =D I have done this and it works- but not quite in the way I had hoped. How would I go about putting both results in the same hashset? I tried changing them to both hashSOne but it didn't compile.