# How to split text into words without spaces and interpunct symbols?

Tags: java, text, split, space, words

I have been given a text from inputstream and first I put it into String via StringBuilder.
Then I want to split the text(now string,since it's not from inputstream) in words, but in some places in the text there are not just one space, but more spaces between the words and interpunct symbols. Programming language should be JAVA.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be using the String split method:

```
String[] words = myString.split(" ");
```

If you have a StringBuilder instead of a String:

```
String[] words = myStringBuilder.toString().split(" ");
```

If you would like to split by any whitespace characters, use [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

```
myString.split("\\s+");
```