# How to print the second word in a line

Tags: java

I have this output and I want to determine the computer with largest price

```
                 Name      Capacity  Price
                -----     -------   -----
Computer  1      Dell        170     292.30
Computer  2        HP         94     452.30
Computer  3    Compaq        167     933.30
Computer  4   Toshiba        162    1171.30
Computer  5      Dell        189    1550.30
Computer  6        HP         53    2027.30
Computer  7     Apple         29    2288.30
Computer  8      Dell         48    2542.30
Computer  9      Dell        128    2700.30
Computer 10    Lenovo        171    2828.30
the computer with max price is :
    Lenovo        171    2828.30
```

I got the code, but it print the whole line, I only want the name of that computer
here is the code

```
System.out.println("the computer with max price is :");
        SortByPrice(list);
        int k = list.length;
        list[k-1].printComputer();
```

I am thinking like having the first index of that line as the name of the computer

Comment: Java or JavaScript, please decide first.

Comment: ...did you write this code?

Answer (score 1):

You need a method that returns the name of the computer, or just do 'list[k-1].name' if name is public.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [`string.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

`list[k-1].printComputer().split("\\s+")[2]`

whitespace split regex from: [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Comment: this assumes `printComputer()` returns a string. if not, you'll have to put the split in wherever it's printing.

Comment: It seems that `printComputer()` doesn't return a string but prints that line to the standard output. Moreover, name is probably the first element after the split.

Comment: `Computer 10    Lenovo` -- the whitespace split on the string would be: computer=0, 10=1, Lenovo=2

Comment: But as you can see `the computer with max price is :
    Lenovo        171    2828.30` so the Lenovo=0, 171=1, 2828.30=2 . It all depends on `printComputer()` :)

Comment: I assumed he was faking the output? We really need to see `printComputer()` to know for sure...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split on tabs instead of spaces, so try:

```
list[k-1].printComputer().split("\t")[2]
```

Comment: if you split on tabs, you probably want index `[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
list[k-1].printComputer().split("\\s+")[0]
```

Comment: it has to be [0] index. he wants to get name of computer so index must be 0. Am i wrong? your answer index is 2 ?

Comment: Read the comments. We're not even sure printcomputer returns a string

Comment: oww now i got it :) i guess it returns string though