# Would there be an approach without using a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, data-structures, arraylist

This is an interview question from 
http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Indeed-Software-Engineer-Interview-Questions-EI_IE100561.0,6_KO7,24.htm , specifically, the problem

"The asked me a method that took in a string and return words up to the max length. There could be any amount of spaces which made it a little tricky "

Here is my solution(with test case)

```
public class MaxLength {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> allWords = maxWords("Jasmine has no love  for chris", 2);
    for(String word: allWords){
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
public static List<String> maxWords(String sentence, int length) {
    String[] words = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String word: words) {
        if(word.length() <= length) {
            list.add(word);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

The test ran fine and i got my expected output - no. However during an actual interview, I think the interviewer doesn't expect you to know this regular expression off the top of your head (I didn't had to find it from [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)) 
Is there another approach to this problem without using regular expressions?

Comment: A question for [this site?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Good call, I post it on their too

Comment: Also, your approach is *inefficient*.. You could do this in one iteration without splitting.

Comment: @TheLostMind Please enlighten me. It made sense me to split so you can   like you said, make one pass.

Comment: It also works when you just pass an white space: `sentence.trim().split(" ");`

Comment: @committedandroider - The value of `maxLength` can change.. My bad... It will need 2 passes..

Comment: @halloei    TheLostMind said that you don't even have to split. If you can't do, how would you differentiate words?

Comment: @TheLostMind So this would be most efficient way to do it then? No other way but to use regular expressions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better ask at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If the interviewer doesn't know `\\s+` of the top of his/her head, I suggest you run and don't look back. ;)

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions though isn't it? I chose to ask on here because theres a lot more users.(more likely to get a response)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Like the interviewer doesn't expect the interviewee to know this at the top of his/her head

Comment: But @Jens in the future, how do i know if a question is more suitable for code review or stack overflow? It's really hard to distinguish for me

Comment: @committedandroider If the interviewer is not looking for the right or best answer, only the answer he/she would have given I would take it as a very bad sign.

Comment: @committedandroider if you have a problem with your code (error unexpected behavior) SO is the correct site. If you would like to have improvements on running code codereview.stackexchange.com is the better choise.

Comment: @committedandroider The way I would do it is; stackoverflow.com - I have some code which doesn't work or is incomplete, how do I get it to work, by any means.  codereview.com - I have code which works, how to I make it better in some way.

Comment: thanks guys!,  that clears it up

Comment: @committedandroider If you give an answer which is more advanced,  simpler, clearer than what they expect, they should see it as a good thing, and you should only work in a place where they want to simplest, clearest code, not following the expected bad practice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the reason I asked is because if this was an actual job interview question, I wouldn't know that exact regular expression so I have to find a way around not using one. I guess I could just say I would use a regular expression though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    public static List<String> maxWords(String sentence, int length) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String tmp = sentence;
        while (tmp.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            String word = tmp.substring(0,tmp.indexOf(" "));
            tmp = tmp.substring(tmp.indexOf(" ")+1);
            if(word.length() <= length) {
                list.add(word);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: This one results in lot of spaces between the words but it does produce the right words though

Comment: @Jens - because subString creates too many well *subStrings*.. :) and `indexOf()` in worst case has to do `n-k` checks.. I am not saying your answer is wrong (better than using *split*).. I am merely saying that there could be a better answer. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind but `split` only works with regex and OP would like to have a solution without using regex.

Comment: @Jens - Right. I am saying your answer is better than using `split()`. :)

Comment: @Jens - Check my answer :) .. Haven't tried it for all inputs, but you will get what I am trying to say..

Comment: I think in Java 7+ substring is O(N), with N=size of the substring. Since this repeatedly uses substring to take the remainder of the string, the entire operation has time complexity O(N^2) with N=size of the sentence. You could avoid this by tracking a current index in the string, and using the overload of indexOf that takes a starting index, instead of shortening the string on each iteration, and get linear time complexity.

Comment: yeah i don't think this would work because spaces are being processed like words

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Another, maybe more lengthy approach would be to iterate over the string and use the methods provided by the Character class ([`Character.isWhiteSpace(char c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))) and break the string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try something like this :
Doesn't create many `subStrings()` just creates subStrings of "matched" Strings

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Jasmine has no love  for chris";
    s=s.trim();
    List<String> ls = getMaxLength(s, 3);
    for (String str : ls) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

static List<String> getMaxLength(String s, int length) {
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    if (s.charAt(i + length) == ' ' || i + length == s.length()) { // search if first word matches your criterion.
        for (i = 1; i < length; i++) { // check for whitespace between 0 and length

            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                i = length;
                break;
            }
            if (i == length - 1)
                ls.add(s.substring(0, length));
        }
    }

    for (i = length; i < s.length(); i++) {// start search from second word..
        if (s.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' && i + length < s.length() // if char at  length is space or end of String, make sure the char before the current char is a space.  
                && (s.charAt(i + length) == ' ' || i + length == s.length())) {
            for (int j = i; j < i + length; j++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                    i = i + length;
                    break;
                }
                if (j == i + length - 1) {
                    ls.add(s.substring(i, i + length));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return ls;
} // end of method
}
```