# How to select an speceific int from a group of ints and doubles that were parsed from a String

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

This is the set of doubles and ints that I parsed is named gradeList, and will be parsed to a constructor. The grade List is:
`"5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88"`
The '5' is an int but everything else should be a double. I parsed it like so

```
public Grades(String gradeList)
{
    Double.parseDouble(gradeList);
    grades = new Grade[5];
}
```

I don´t know how to take in the '5' as the length of an array and the other 5 doubles be the data inside of the new array.

Comment: does your code do anything like what you expect from it?

Comment: I want to go step bu step. I want it to create an array of size 5, but it does not even crash, it just keeps running on forever.

Comment: What about the "- " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way could be:

```
String gradeList = "5 - 90 85 95.5 77.5 88";
String gradeArray [] = gradeList.split(" ");
int firstElement = Integer.parseInt(gradeArray[0]);
double gradeDoubleArray [] = new double[firstElement];
for(int i = 2; i < firstElement + 2; i++){
    gradeDoubleArray[i-2] = Double.parseDouble(gradeArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize (split) on whitespace. Grab the first item as the array size and convert the rest.

This stackoverflow page shows how to split on whitespace
[How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Comment: and what about the "-"?

Comment: But how do I take just the first item?

Comment: You can parse on '-' and whitespace.  Using guava (which is awesome).  Iterable<String> x = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("- ")).split(str);   will work for - and a space.  Splitter returns an iterable, so the first time you call next(), it will give you the first element.