# Bit Manipulation Java

Tags: java, byte, bit

So, Supposing I have the byte set

```
0101 0101 0110 0010 1101 0100 1111 0010 1011 0010 0101 1010
```

How would I do to get every byte independently? For example, printing them so the output is:

```
0101
0101
0110
0010
1101
0100
1111
1101
0010
1011
0010
0101
1010
```

Thanks a Lot!

Some Code:

```
protected String parse(StringBuilder builder) {

    String pBinary = getBinary(p);
    String qBinary = getBinary(q);
}

private String getBinary(BigInteger integer) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (byte bytes : integer.toByteArray()) {
        builder.append(" ");

        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(bytes));

        if (binary.length() != 8)
            for (int i = binary.length(); i < 8; i++)
                builder.append(0);

        builder.append(binary);
    }

    return builder.substring(1);
}
```

p and q are BigIntegers.

The idea is to insert at the start of the StringBuilder a "Mixture" of both binaries.

So if *binary 1* is *01101001 01010111* and **binary 2** is **10111010**,

the mixture will result in *01101001* **00000000** *01010111* **10111010**

Comment: A byte is 8 bit (not 4).

Comment: Given no further details, I would copy/paste your line into Notepad and manually insert CRLF to create the output list.

Comment: Do you actually read a binary stream as input, or do you get a binary string (a string only containing characters '0' and '1')?

Comment: I'm reading the bytes from 2 BigIntegers, and need to "mix" them so the first byte corresponds to the first integer, the second one to the second integer, the third one to the first integer and so

Comment: This sounds absolutely hazy. Do show some code.

Comment: Ok, added it to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string that has words separated by spaces you can do

`String[] words = myString.split("\\s+")`

More detailed answer here, [How do I split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters)

Comment: Very funny indeed!