# Infix to postfix read negative integers as negative

Tags: java.util.scanner, calculator, infix-operator

Im doing a calculator for schoolwork and everything works except my scanner, cause when it takes a negative integer it doesnt see it as a negative number it just sees the subtraction sign as a operator and I want it to see it like a part of the operand:

```
String exp = "8+4*-12-4";
    String[] temp = new String[exp.length()];
    temp =exp.split("(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])");
```

this makes it correct if its only positive integers.
for example 
input: 8+4*12-4
and the 
output:[8, 4, 12, *, +, 4, -]

but with a negative number it doesnt get it right!
so thats what I want help with, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList <String>list= new LinkedList<String>();`
just takes each of the characters in the string and adds each to the resulting list.   Instead of doing this, you need to write syntax-aware code.  If you can insist on white space between all tokens, then you can split on spaces [with, for example, `String.split`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters).   If not, the simplest alternative is to iterate over the characters in the string "by hand" and create the output that way.

While I suppose it is also possible to use `String.split` with a non-capturing  positive lookahead to also split on operators, figuring out regular expressions to that level of mastery is more difficult than solving the problem in code.  I can't give an example for the positive lookahead assertion implementation, as I don't want to take the time to run up a development envirionment, write the code, create test cases and debug it - since I don't think this is the approach you should take in any case.

Comment: could you give me an example on how you could use split in this case? Ive been googling but cant really find a good example, thanks in advance