# Match expressions separated by spaces

Tags: regex, numbers

I have the following line:

```
1 2/5 0.4 1+3i
```

Each group can be separated by one or more spaces. The first one, can have spaces or not before him. The last one can have spaces or not after him.

I want to get:

```
1
2/5
0.4
1+3i
```

How can I get them with regex?
To be simple I tried on a shorter example because complex is the more difficult:

```
2 3i
```

I tried with the following regex:

```
/\s*((?:[\d]+)|(?:[\d]*\i))/g
```

But I get the `i` separated from its integer:

```
2
3
i
```

I can't find a good regex for my problem. Any solution?

Comment: **[this](https://regex101.com/r/dH1dZ4/2)**

Comment: Duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters

Comment: I am using C++. I'm not looking just for separating string surrounded by spaces. I'm only looking for integers, fractionnal and complex numbers separated by spaces. So not everything

Comment: in that case you can use match :- **[like](https://regex101.com/r/dH1dZ4/3)**

Comment: @rock321987 your solution works. post as answer?

Comment: Okay @rock321987 your solution is actually working fine. But I would like to catch complex numbers without real part, like this: `4i` or just `i`. I'm not very friendly with regex, I tried to edit your solution but failed. Could you please help me a bit more for that? Thanks

Comment: wait for few minutes..having my dinner

Comment: For sure ahah, no prob' @rock321987, take your time & thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of split like

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))|((?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?i)|([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\/(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)) #For fractional part
  |
((?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?i) #For complex number
  |
([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) #For any numbers
```

*Further Breakdown*

```
(
   (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?) #Match any number with or without decimal
     \/ #Match / literally
   (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?) #Match any number with or without decimal
) #For fractional part

| #Alternation(OR)

(
   (?:[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) #Match real part of the number
   ? #This makes real part optional
   [+-]? #Match + or - and make it optional for cases like \di
   (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)? #Match the digits of imaginary part (optional if we want to match only i)
   i #Match i
) #For complex number

| #Alternation(OR)

([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?) #Match any numbers with or without decimal
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH1dZ4/5)**

Comment: Wow really nice answer! Thanks a lot!
One last thing: how is it possible to match fractional in the real and imaginary part of a complex?

Comment: @SylvainM just take care not to put the last term of alternation `([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` to starting or middle..otherwise it will be wrong..

Comment: @SylvainM can you give an example?

Comment: Okay!
I would like to match something like `1/2+2/3i` with `1/2` the real part and `3/2` the imaginary one, in addition to the current features of the version you gave.

Comment: @SylvainM so it can be `1i/2+2/3i`?

Comment: No, it must be `a+bi` where `a` and `b` can be integer/real or fractional like `x/y`. But not the form `ai/b` or something like that.

Comment: @SylvainM glad to help..enjoy