# What does s.split("\\s+")) means here in the below code?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

I am given a String name say String s in below code. This String contains a phrase i.e. one or more words separated by single spaces. This program computes and return the acronym of this phrase.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Initials {
  public String getInitials(String s) {

    String r = "";
    for(String t:s.split("\\s+")){
      r += t.charAt(0);
    }
    return r;
  }


  void p(Object... o) {
          System.out.println(deepToString(o));
      }


}
```

Example:
"john fitzgerald kennedy"

Returns: "jfk"

Comment: What documentation tells you? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: See this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters

Comment: It means that someone didn't understand that String.split() without any parameters already means split on white space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means: slice the input string *s* on the given regular expression.

That regular expression simply says: "one or more whitespaces".
(see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for an extensive descriptions what those patterns mean)

Thus: that call to split returns an array with "john", "fitzgerald", ...
That array is directly "processed" using the for-each type of for loops.

When you then pick the first character of each of those strings, you end up with "jfk"

Answer (score 18):

`split("\\s+")` will split the string into string of array with separator as space or multiple spaces. `\s+` is a regular expression for one or more spaces.