# How can I split strings correctly?

Tags: java, string, split

So I want to split a `String` into strings, for example I have a `String` "Hello! I am trying to lea?!!rn java" and I want to have Strings like
"Hello","I","am","trying","to","learn" and "java", what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Is your string supposed to have `?!!` in the middle of it, or is that a typo?

Comment: consider looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: This might be a duplicate of Maciej's link, and it might be a duplicate of Berger's link, or it might be a unique combination of the two which means it's not a duplicate. Regardless, Jaime, you really should show us the code you've used, what its output is, and why you feel that output is different from what you want it to do. That's going to give you the best results here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
String string = "Hello! I am trying to learn java";
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```

And tell your teacher where you got the answer from.

Comment: Pxaxaxaxaxa you've made my day xD