# Java - How to split a string on "space" with a fraction char like "1 ½"?

Tags: java

So I want to be able do split this string by spaces:
"1 ½ cups fat-free half-and-half, divided "

I wrote my code like this:

```
String trimmed;
String[] words = trimmed.split(" ");
```

But it doesn't work! The 1 and the ½ end up in the same position of the array.

I also tried [How to split a string with any whitespace chars as delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-to-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters) but it does not split string either. Looking in text editor there is clearly some sort of "space" but I don't get how to split on it. Is is because of "½"?

Comment: Use `System.out.println((int)trimmed.charAt(1));` to see what the second character in the string is. It might be something other than a regular space, e.g. a no-break space

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  It doesn't.  I tried validating if `\s` would do it and it's not able to do it by itself.

Comment: @Makoto is right, as per `java.util.regex.Pattern` documentation, `\s` does not match `\u2009`.

Comment: @Makoto I've updated the question to clarify that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a [thin space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2009) there instead of a "regular" space character.

[image]

Regex capturing of this is not trivial, as there are other character classes you need to capture.  You would at a minimum want to capture it as an additional grouping...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(\\s|\\u2009)")));
```

...but you would also [need to include *all* the other non-standard white space characters](https://gist.github.com/johnywith1n/6944482) in this search just to be sure you don't miss any.  The above works for your case.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the pattern, and you can directly use the Unicode escape in the String literal, no need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the space between `1` and `½` is not a regular space (U+0020) but instead a "thin space" (U+2009).

Since `String.split(String)` accepts a regex pattern, you could for example use the pattern `\h` instead which represents a "horizontal whitespace character", see [`Pattern` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and matches U+2009.
Or you could use the pattern `" |\u2009"`.