# How do I exclude numbers from my word count?

Tags: java

I wanted to make a word count, but exclude all of the words that started with a number.

The code below is supposed to print the number 4, but it instead prints 5.

```
public class WordCountLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Words = "This is a test123 123";
       int WordCount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Words.length(); i++)
        {
            if (Words.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                WordCount++;
            
                if (Character.isDigit(Words.charAt(i)))
                {

                    WordCount++;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of words is " + WordCount); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your code's logic. If `Words.charAt(i)==' '` then `Character.isDigit(Words.charAt(i))` is false (a character cannot be a space and a digit at the same time). Better yet, use `String.split()` method to separate words.

Comment: You want to [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). That will give you an array of `String`. You can then iterate through the array, testing the first character of each element.  If you want to split on any whitespace character, see the checked answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225337/how-to-split-a-string-with-any-whitespace-chars-as-delimiters

Comment: your logic doesn't make sense: a char at any position ca have exactly one value :) use a piece of paper or a debugger to work through it

Answer (score 1):

Use String.split so you don't have to check for spaces

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String words = "This is a test123 123";
        int wordCount = 0;
        for (String word : words.split(" "))
        {
            if (!Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0)))
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number of words is " + wordCount); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isDigit()` check doesn't belong inside the `if`. You need to move it into the `if` *condition*, and you want to check the *next* character before incrementing:

```
if (Words.charAt(i) == ' '
        && i + 1 < Words.length()
        && !Character.isDigit(Words.charAt(i + 1)))
{
    WordCount++;
}
```

Note that only checking digits means *any* other character following a space is considered a new word, including symbols or additional spaces.

Comment: @DYZ You mean if there are 2 spaces.

Comment: My bad, I did not notice the second term.